# What are Local declarations for : variables, functions and classes In Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

So i started learning `kotlin` for android development.
But when i get to the visibility topic i met this note stating:

> Local declarations
>   Local variables, functions and classes can not have visibility modifiers.

What are `Local declarations` in `Kotlin`   ?

I asked you here witch means i already did a search on the internet but the only results i have got they were about java and other programming  languages and i don't want to mix up things so i  can  avoid confusion.
Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Can you add a little bit of your code?

Comment: Code ! for what !? did you understand  what i mean  i don't have a code issue ! i only want to understand a meaning

Comment: I googled it for you: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i don't how i missed that !

Answer (score 1):

Local declarations are declarations placed inside a body of a function (or a constructor, an `init` block, or a property accessor).

These declarations can only be referenced inside the lexical scope where they are declared:

```
fun foo() { 
    if (Random().nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
        fun bar() { 
            println("bar") 
        }

        bar() // OK
    } else {
        bar() // Error: unresolved reference
    }
}
```

Consequently, these declarations can never be used outside the body, and therefore visibility modifiers (which normally control whether a declaration is accessible outside the type or the file) are meaningless for local declarations.

Local declarations can be used for entities that have meaning only inside a body of the function and not anywhere else, or should not be used anywhere else.

An example of a valid use case for local declarations is a `data class` for intermediate values of a calculation:

```
fun getAndSaveEmails(people: List<Person>) { 
    data class PersonWithEmail(
        val person: Person, 
        val email: String
    )

    val peopleWithEmails = people.map { PersonWithEmail(it, requestEmail(it)) }

    peopleWithEmails.forEach { save(it.person, it.email) }
}
```